# Multiple Replacements with Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Ok so an Imperial Agent has gained access to all the Galactic mail servers and has created a mail account for Darth Vadar on each one...

There is a master distribution list maintained in an Oracle Column by the Republic that looks like this:

`~To,Chewie,ChewBacca@wookie.net~;~Cc,Han Solo,Millenium@Falcon.com~;~Cc,Luke Skywalker,Luke@IamYourFather.co.uk~`

Our Imperial Agent needs help using Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE to replace all the email account names portions with the Darth Vadar account, Vadar@...  so the end result would be:

`~To,Chewie,Vadar@wookie.net~;~Cc,Han Solo,Vadar@Falcon.com~;~Cc,Luke Skywalker,Vadar@IamYourFather.co.uk~`

Can this be done as a single statement?
You would think that using the Dark Force would be easier then this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be too simple for some cases, but for your example this works:

```
regexp_replace(value, '[[:alnum:]\.]*@', 'Vadar@')
```

e.g:

```
select regexp_replace('~To,Chewie,ChewBacca@wookie.net~;~Cc,Han Solo,Millenium@Falcon.com~;~Cc,Luke Skywalker,Luke@IamYourFather.co.uk~',
  '[[:alnum:].%_+-]*@', 'Vadar@')
from dual;


~To,Chewie,Vadar@wookie.net~;~Cc,Han Solo,Vadar@Falcon.com~;~Cc,Luke Skywalker,Vadar@IamYourFather.co.uk~
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6666c/130) with dash and period examples.

Comment: If we add Obi-Wan to the mix we have trouble.  `~To,Chewie,ChewBacca@wookie.net~;~Cc,Han Solo,Millenium@Falcon.com~;~Cc,Luke Skywalker,Luke@IamYourFather.co.uk~;~Cc,Obi-Wan Kenobi,Obi-Wan@JediCouncil.au~`

Comment: @CapitalBoo - said it might be too simple. I'd already allowed for periods, but now expanded the pattern to include other valid characters. This may still not be everything allowed by RFC 5322, and only covers English, but not sure what scope you're dealing with.